# Why do my service charges keep saying 0 instead of 206?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't find out why my code is not adding in the oil lube, flush, and misc checkboxes towards the service charge label. I have them added in the calculate button and they are all declared but I still end up with 0. For example, if oil change, transmission flush, and muffler are checked i should end up with 206. Does anyone have an idea why i still end up with 0? Thanks!

```
namespace Semester_Projectt
{

    public partial class semesterProject : Form
    {
        double oilChange;
        double lubeJob;
        double radiatorFlush;
        double transmissionFlush;
        double inspection;
        double muffler;
        double tireRotation;
        const double taxRate = 0.06;

        public semesterProject()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private double OilLubeCharges(double oilChange, double lubeJob)
        {
            return oilChange + lubeJob;
        }
        private double FlushCharges(double radiatorFlush, double transmissionFlush)
        {
            return radiatorFlush + transmissionFlush;
        }
        private double MiscCharges(double inspection, double muffler, double tireRotation)
        {
            return inspection + muffler + tireRotation;
        }
        private double OtherCharges(double parts, double labor)
        {
            return parts + labor;
        }
        private double TaxCharges(double parts)
        {
            if (parts != 0)
            {
                return (0.06 * parts);
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        private double TotalCharges(double oilLube, double flush, double misc, double other, double tax)
        {
            return oilLube + flush + misc + other + tax;
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearOilLube();
            ClearFlushes();
            ClearMisc();
            ClearOther();
            ClearFees();
        }
        private void ClearOilLube()
        {
            if(oilCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                oilCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
            if(lubeCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lubeCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        private void ClearFlushes()
        {
            if(radiatorCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                radiatorCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
            if(transmissionCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                transmissionCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        private void ClearMisc()
        {
            if(inspectionCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                inspectionCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
            if(mufflerCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                mufflerCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
            if(tireCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                tireCheckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        private void ClearOther()
        {
            partsTextBox.Text = "";
            laborTextBox.Text = "";
        }
        private void ClearFees()
        {
            serviceChargeLabel.Text = "";
            additionalPartsLabel.Text = "";
            additionalLaborLabel.Text = "";
            taxLabel.Text = "";
            totalFeesLabel.Text = "";
        }
        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);
            double labor = double.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);
            double oilLube = OilLubeCharges(oilChange, lubeJob);
            double flush = FlushCharges(radiatorFlush, transmissionFlush);
            double misc = MiscCharges(inspection, muffler, tireRotation);
            double other = OtherCharges(parts, labor);
            double tax = TaxCharges(parts);
            double total = TotalCharges(oilLube, flush, misc, other, tax);
            double services = oilLube + flush + misc;

            serviceChargeLabel.Text = services.ToString("c");
            additionalPartsLabel.Text = parts.ToString("c");
            additionalLaborLabel.Text = labor.ToString("c");
            taxLabel.Text = tax.ToString("c");
            totalFeesLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");

            try
            {
                parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);

                try
                {
                    labor = double.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    partsTextBox.Focus();
                    partsTextBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                laborTextBox.Focus();
                laborTextBox.SelectAll();
            }

            if (oilCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                oilChange = 26.00;
            }
            if (lubeCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lubeJob = 18.00;
            }
            if (radiatorCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                radiatorFlush = 30.00;
            }
            if (transmissionCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                transmissionFlush = 80.00;
            }
            if (inspectionCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                inspection = 15.00;
            }
            if (mufflerCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                muffler = 100.00;
            }
            if (tireCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                tireRotation = 20.00;
            }
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But... you check the checkboxes for being checked after you calculate the total? C# executes in top-to-bottom order, so you can't hope that `var oil = 0; var water = 0; var total = oil + water; oil = 10;` will mean that total is 10

Comment: You need to assign the values to the service checkboxes `value` property regardless of its `checked` state.  Only sum `checked` services.

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried it with the calculate button at the top, but that didn't really change anything

Comment: Changing the position of a button on a form isn't going to change anything, nor is changing what line number a method is declared on in the class file. I was talking about the order of the lines inside the calculate method; first you sum the total up, then you set the values of the things you sum. That's not going to work

Comment: @fnostro er.. class level variables get default values, so that isn't true

Comment: @CaiusJard: Not talking about the class variables, but their associated html elements (checkboxes in this case). i.e. it's odd to me to be doing this `if( xCheckbox.Checked ){x=26)` rather than `if(xCheckbox.Checked){s+=xCheckbox.value}` where `x` is the html element and `s` is a summation of services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step through your code using the debugger and I think you'll see that all of your cost variables (i.e. `oilChange`) are 0 when you sum them together.

After you show the MessageBoxes, you have several IF statements that set the variable costs if the checkboxes are checked.  It looks like those IF statements should be moved to the top of the procedure.